# How to change local IP to domain name so a host can access a VM?

Tags: windows-7, networking, debian, domain

I've managed to set up a Debian server (in a VM) and now I can access it in the Windows 7 host at `192.168.56.101`

Is there any way to "map" that IP to a domain name? It doesn't have to be accessible from the internet, just from the host. Because it's annoying to type the IP in the browser every time I want to access it.

Comment: Have you tried connecting via \\<vm name>?

Comment: Are you running `nmbd` in the guest?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what's that :) How do I check if I am?

Comment: What do you mean "access/map?" You mentioned you are using a browser, are you trying to connect to a Web server you have installed?

Comment: Yes. It's apache running on debian, which is running in virtualbox, under windows 7

Comment: Put an entry into your hosts file that has the desired host name pointed at the ip.

Comment: in `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very easy to do, find your Windows 7 hosts file and put an entry in it. The Windows 7 system will now be able to resolve the name to the IP. I'm running a similar dev environment as to what you're describing. Windows 7 Host running Virtual Box with an Ubuntu server VM.

Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Add a line as follows

```
92.168.56.101           www.example.dev
```